# how to make a command list discord commands in discord.js

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a command that lists all of the commands like this:

1. command 1
2. command 2
3. command 3
   etc.

**How can I do this? I have tried this:

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'help',
    description: "Lists commands",
    execute(message, args) {
    message.channel.send('Prefix = !  hello: greets you in different languages  ping: :ping_pong:  help: Shows this List  info: Shows Info About @LlamaBot#0241');
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the problem here? The fact that there is no linebreak?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code:

```
const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");
    
    module.exports = {
      name: "help",
      description: "Help cmd",
      execute: async (client, message, args) => {
        const newEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
    
        .setColor('#000000')
        .setTitle('Commands')
        .setDescription('Commands')
        .addFields(
            {name: 'command', value: '-command'},
        )
    
        message.channel.send(newEmbed);
      }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really improve the quality of your post and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you answer the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and indicate what limitations and assumptions apply.